# How to make a two divs stack on top of eachother when screen width becomes too small

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following section that contains a div called `programDescriptionDiv`.  `programDescriptionDiv` has two separate divs in it.  By default, the two divs take up 50% of the screen width.

I would like for the second div to stack below the first one when the screen becomes too small to accomodate both divs on the same row (which is what `flex-wrap: wrap` should do, but is not doing.

As of right now, when the screen width becomes too small, the two divs just stretch and contract to continue filling 50% of the screen width.  I would like the divs to stack on top of eachother instead.  What is wrong in my CSS?

HTML:

```html
<section class="programDescriptionSection">
  <div class="programDescriptionDiv">
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img id="closingStemGapImage" src="../resources/closingStemGap.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="paragraphDiv">
      <p class="homepageSectionParagraph">
        The Codigo Initiative aims to close the STEM opportunity divide in under-resourced Chicago-area school districts by connecting classroom
        teachers with tech-industry professionals. This pairing creates sustainable Computer Programming curriculums where volunteers support
        teachers as they learn the basics of Computer Programming.  Ultimately, the teachers will infuse their newly-found STEM skills into their
        existing classroom curriculums. The end-result is an enhanced classroom experience where teachers empower their students to compete in today's
        economy, and inspire them to create a better future for themselves and their communities.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```css
.programDescriptionSection {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* align-items: center; center all contents vertically */
  justify-content: center;
  /*center horizontally*/
}

.programDescriptionDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  /*center all contents vertically*/
  justify-content: center;
  /*center horizontally*/
  width: 100%;
  /*make the section take up the whole width of the screen*/
  flex-direction: row;
}

.imageDiv {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*center all contents vertically*/
  justify-content: center;
  /*center horizontally*/
  min-width: 50%;
}

#closingStemGapImage {
  /*Will fir the dimensions of the div dynamically.*/
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.paragraphDiv {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*center all contents vertically*/
  justify-content: center;
  /*center horizontally*/
}

.homepageSectionParagraph {
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you're not setting a width constraint on your flex items. You can do this by changing the `min-width` property to your breakpoint. You can also use media queries.

```css
.programDescriptionSection {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* align-items: center; center all contents vertically */
    justify-content: center; /*center horizontally*/
}

.programDescriptionDiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center; /*center all contents vertically*/
    justify-content: center; /*center horizontally*/
    width: 100%; /*make the section take up the whole width of the screen*/
    flex-direction: row;
}

.imageDiv{
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /*center all contents vertically*/
    justify-content: center; /*center horizontally*/
    min-width: 500px; /*set to your breakpoint*/
}

#closingStemGapImage{
    /*Will fir the dimensions of the div dynamically.*/
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.paragraphDiv{
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /*center all contents vertically*/
    justify-content: center; /*center horizontally*/
}

.homepageSectionParagraph{
    font-size: 90%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<section class="programDescriptionSection">
            <div class="programDescriptionDiv">
                <div class="imageDiv">
                    <img id="closingStemGapImage" src="https://www.plextek.com/wp-content/uploads/default-placeholder-1024x1024-500x500-1.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="paragraphDiv">
                    <p class="homepageSectionParagraph">
                        The Codigo Initiative aims to close the STEM opportunity divide in under-resourced Chicago-area school districts by connecting classroom
                        teachers with tech-industry professionals. This pairing creates sustainable Computer Programming curriculums where volunteers support
                        teachers as they learn the basics of Computer Programming.  Ultimately, the teachers will infuse their newly-found STEM skills into their
                        existing classroom curriculums. The end-result is an enhanced classroom experience where teachers empower their students to compete in today's
                        economy, and inspire them to create a better future for themselves and their communities.
                    </p>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </section>
```